# Cresomo 101oz Stainless Steel Vacuum Airpot plunger stuck after cleaning?

Tags: coffee

The plunger or stem in my Cresomo 101oz Stainless Steel Vacuum Airpot is stuck after I cleaned it once after receiving and taking out of the package to wash it.

I've heard it suggested that I could get it out of there by heating it up; and I've also heard that I could use a pair of tongs to pull it out; but neither has worked, and the rubber plunger remains lodged below the hole in the middle of it.

Both of the people I talked to who gave me the advice above, work in the Food and Beverage Industry.

What else can I do to pull that plunger out of it so that it can be used for the first time?

Comment: It sounds as if it's broken to me, wend it back under guarantee and get a replacement.

Comment: are you able to provide a picture that shows where it is stuck?

Comment: I fixed it; I used a pair of needle nosed pliers.